# Background BLE operation with iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

i’m trying to perform the following operations with the `Core Bluetooth Framework` of `iOS`:

1) Connection to peripheral

2) Services Discovery

3) Characteristics Discovery

4) Start Notify on a particular characteristic

These operations have to be triggered in background, when a callback not related to Core Bluetooth (`Core Location Framework`) fires up.

I have correctly set the Bluetooth Background settings for the app and when the application is put in background through the central button, all is ok: core location callback fires up and the core bluetooth steps are executed correctly.
The problem comes when the application is killed by swiping up with the task manager: in this case when the core location callback fires up the phone is able to connect to the peripheral (1) but it does not discover services.

I’m using iPhone 6 with iOS 10.3.1 and micro nrf51822.

Here is my code:

CBCentralManager initialization (viewDidLoad)

```
self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:@{ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@“myCentralManagerIdentifier”}];
```

Core Location Callback:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    NSLog(@“*** enter region”);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *savedUuid = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@“preferenceUuid”];
        if (savedUuid!=NULL){
            NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:savedUuid];
            NSArray *arrayUuid = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:uuid, nil];
            _knownPeripheral = [[self.centralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:arrayUuid] objectAtIndex:0];
        }
        if (_knownPeripheral!=NULL){
            [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:_knownPeripheral options:nil];
        }
    });
}
```

CoreBluetooth Callbacks:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral(CBPeripheral *)peripheral { 
    [self.knownPeripheral discoverServices:nil]; 
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error {
    //Core Bluetooth creates an array of CBService objects —- one for each service that is discovered on the peripheral.
    for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {
        if (([service.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:K_BT_SERVICE_BATTERY]])) {
             [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
        }
    }
}

- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:K_BT_CHARACTERISTIC_BATTERY]]) {
            [self.sensorTag setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
        }
    }
}
```

How can i perform correctly the steps from 1) to 4) when the application is awaked from a killed state?

Thank you

Comment: ViewDidLoad is not executed when an app is re-lanched in the background

Comment: I moved the CBCentralManager initialization in application delegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions). I have also moved all the BLE related methods in the application delegate which now conforms to CBCentralManagerDelegate and CBPeripheralDelegate protocols. Unfortunately i get the same behavior